# Running “apt-get update” returns an error “apt-secure(8)”

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I have the Ubuntu Game Pack and I'm trying to use `sudo apt-get update` and it's returing the error

```
W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
W: The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1484261108
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease:

all have such problems (I also have) - Intel is lazy to create the right key - do not worry

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/new-ubuntu-16.04-packages-use-unknown-key-again

2. run commands:

   `wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -`

   `sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`
3. `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list"`

   `wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key`

   `sudo apt-key add - < Release.key`

   `sudo apt-get update`

https://www.ostechnix.com/manage-games-using-lutris-linux/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, however I still have one error,

Comment: W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Comment: That a warning (W), not an error (E) and not solvable from your side.

Answer (score 3):

remove `sources.list` and `index.html` in `/etc/apt` dir

```
cp /etc/apt/preferences.d/index.html /tmp
rm -rf /etc/apt/preferences.d/index.html
cp /etc/apt/sources.list  /tmp
rm -rf sources.list
```

then reboot

Answer (score 2):

Just go to update GUI and 'unclick' every "other software". Refresh cache is going to work well now, and 'sudo apt update' as well.